# Can 'on the outside' be replaced by just 'outside'?

Tags: difference

I understand that the phrase **on the outside** is commonly used. However, I wonder if I can leave out **on the**.

Here's a sentence I took from [this](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/on-the-outside)

> He may be cheerful **on the outside**, but that’s not how he feels.

Why is this not:

> He may be cheerful **outside**, but that’s not how he feels.

for the sake of simplicity?

I have 3 possibility thoughts about this problem:

1. They have different meanings.
2. Both are OK and *always* be OK.
3. Sometimes we *must* put **on the** before outside depends on the context.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those mean two different things.

> He may be cheerful outside...

This means that he is outdoors/not inside a building, so saying

> He may be cheerful outside, but that’s not how he feels.

would get you strange looks from native speakers

Comment: I generally agree that "he's cheerful outside" sounds like "he is cheerful when he is outside", but I think it sometimes depends on context.  For example, "You know how Duncan is: calm and collected outside, a raging mess inside" would probably be interpreted to mean "Duncan's inside or outside", not "when Duncan is inside or when he is outside".